# Troubleshoot: Setting up rails project with nginx + passenger locally (on a mac)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, configuration, passenger, osx-yosemite

Problem: I installed nginx + passenger on my local computer, but I can't connect my rails project to nginx. Here's what I did:

1. I've installed nginx + passenger using brew, as instructed here:
   https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/osx/
2. I edited the config file (under /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf) to the following:

   ```
   http {
       passenger_root /usr/local/opt/passenger/libexec/lib/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
       passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
       ...

       server {
           listen 3000;
           server_name localhost;
           rails_env development;
           root /absolute/path/to/rails/project/public
           passenger_enabled on;
       }

       location / {
           root html;
           index index.html index.htm;
       }

       ...
   }
   ```
3. Then I start nginx by typing "nginx" in terminal
4. Now when I go to localhost:3000, all I get is the default "Welcome to nginx!" page. What I expect to see is my home root page.

Questions 
- What am I doing wrong? aka, why is the rails project not showing? 
- Any recommendations for troubleshooting?

Note 
- localhost:3000 works if I'm run "rails server" (webrick) 
- Running Rails 3.2.19, ruby 2.1.4, nginx 1.8, Phusion Passenger 5.0.18.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you started the rails application server (phusion passenger)?

Comment: Also, personally I would go for unicorn with nginx...

Comment: @RubyRacer I thought just starting the nginx was sufficient? If not, do I run passenger on a separate port? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Well, I was wrong, apparently you don't need to start phusion passenger with nginx, you do however need to supply a good `passenger_root`. Good meaning, it has to be a directory, not a file, as in your conf.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

This is likely to be an Nginx issue. I recommend that you use Passenger Standalone so that you don't have to deal with Nginx. It's much easier. Just run 'passenger start' in your application directory.

Comment: I want to emulate the production environment as much as possible when I test locally. Do you know how to go about debugging this Nginx issue?